# Karma for automatic user interaction testing?

Tags: automated-tests, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm testing a setup with [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) + [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/). One of the things this *might (?)* do is testing user-interaction on a variety of browsers including [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless webkit).

I say **might** because I'm not sure how to get basic PhantomJS functionality to work within a  Karma+Mocha setting. I.e:  `var page = require("webpage").create();` is supposed to be a canonical example in PhantomJS to start-off with, but Karma can't locate `require`.

Now, I might be able to solve this by including `require.js` to Karma, but before I'm "require-izing" my project, I'd like to know if Karma+PhantomJS is indeed meant to test automatic interactions like:

1. load page x
2. fill in form
3. submit
4. check if everything went well on the client

Are these kinds of interaction-tests possible with Karma + phantomJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS is a node-independent [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/)/[WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) based library. It has a scripting environment that is very similar to node, but is not node. From the home page:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It
>   has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling,
>   CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

Karma interacts with PhantomJS as it would any other browser it supports (FireFox, Chrome etc) - to load a page, inject some tests into it via WebSockets, run them and gather the results.

The type of tests you describe are better suited to an acceptance test framework (I prefer [Capybara](http://jnicklas.github.io/capybara/)), [WebDriver based tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools), or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) (taken directly from the home page):

> CasperJS is an open source navigation scripting & testing utility
>   written in Javascript for the PhantomJS WebKit headless browser and
>   SlimerJS (Gecko). It eases the process of defining a full navigation
>   scenario and provides useful high-level functions, methods & syntactic
>   sugar for doing common tasks such as:
>
> - defining & ordering browsing navigation steps
> - filling & submitting forms
> - clicking & following links
> - capturing screenshots of a page (or part of it)
> - testing remote DOM
> - logging events
> - downloading resources, including binary ones
> - writing functional test suites, saving results as JUnit XML
> - scraping Web contents

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Do you know of any acceptance/end-to-end test frameworks like CasperJS that would allow for testing on multiple browers? It would be ideal to be able to do continuous testing locally (on each change) using something like CasperJS + PhantomJS and have some CI-server test the same specs on a variety of real browsers when pushing to staging/prod

Comment: Selenium WebDriver (and/or Selenium Grid) is industry standard, and there are many wrapper libraries depending on your language of choice. Node: https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs  Ruby: Capybara/Watir and mature Java/Python/your-language-here etc exist