# How can I write a script to automatically walk through a process like my user would?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have some valuable processes on my site that I'd like to track regularly to make sure they are working. I wrote some javascript that will run the actions if the starting page contains a particular parameter, but I can't figure out how to properly execute the script without opening the page in a browser.

My best guess is I need some sort of chron driven bot for this, but I don't even know where I should begin with that and haven't found anything in my searching. I tried a cURL request, but it doesn't seem to fire the js. Really, if I could just find a way to properly initialize the js with a chron job that would be sufficient.

**The key here is that I need it to execute the javascript so I can imitate user actions**.

I'm working on a WordPress install, so it would need to be a php or javascript based solution. How can I build something like this?

Comment: anything that should run with out a browser(automated) should not be written in JaveScript

Comment: @Dagon - how would you recommend checking a process like this?

Comment: a server side language, not a client side one

Comment: @Dagon - You can run javascript on the server.

Comment: @Dagon - a server site language wouldn't emulate the user's actions, which is the whole point of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interaction testing framework like **[Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-user-interaction/)**. that should allow you to test your UI Interactions.

See the link above to get some detailed information on how to use the library.

Here is a code snippet from the Ember.js library to see if a user is 
 
redirected properly if not authenticated (100% javascript!):

```
module('Integration: Transitions', {
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test('redirect to login if not authenticated', function() {
  visit('/');
  click('.profile');

  andThen(function() {
    equal(currentRouteName(), 'login');
    equal(currentPath(), 'login');
    equal(currentURL(), '/login');
  });
});
```

**Ember.js is an excellent way to test your user interactions and your UI components.**

Learn more here: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-user-interaction/

**UPDATE:** 

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196926/3960969) for another solution that combines CasperJS and PhantomJS to test user interfaces.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Yeah, its an awesome framework. It will really help your workflow. Have fun writing your tests! =)

Comment: Nice, thanks! Do you know if it can ping urls on a different server as well? So if I have a network of sites I can install on one server and test sites on other servers?

Comment: **Ember.js is not a testing framework.** It is a Javascript web framework. It contains some tools for testing code written for Ember, but cannot be used to test server-side code.

Comment: You can use the testing framework to test your user interfaces. And the author doesn't want to test his server-side code, he wants to test his user interfaces, which live on the client side.

Comment: @JeremiahPrummer As long as your testing files can reach the network without access restriction, then yes, you should be able to test in this way.

Comment: @radiovisual cool thank you. I'm researching now. This is definitely the best find yet. Unfortunately I can only give you one upvote. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have a browser open to do it you could use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks for this! Not sure this is exactly what I'm after, but it looks better than most